# rails csrf token lifetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, csrf

I use Rails `request_forgery_protection` mechanism to protect my POST actions from CSRF attacks and captcha to protect the GET actions. This way if someone stages a two-phase attack within one session, GET-ting the form with the current token and then POST-ing a forged request with that token, he will eventually be faced with a captcha check.

I'm stuck with that though, because Rails doesn't regenerate the CSRF token until the end of session. That doesn't seem right to me, I'd think the token should be renewed before the next action. I'm wondering maybe I have tweaked something wrong? Is there another way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case form token is NOT regenerated for each page request, this protection is bad. I faced it sometime ago (when testing Redmine, which is RoR-based) and reported this issue, but didn't retested it.

If it's still not regenerated, I suggest you report this to RoR team.

Comment: I'm glad we agree that a persistent token is useless :) Though even if the RoR team fixed it, I really don't see how it could work without placing some serious constraints on site architecture or leaving gaps in security. I'm afraid I'll have to lean more on captcha.

Comment: note that regenerating the token for every request has some impact in term of usability (back won't work for instance) see: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation%3a_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern

Answer (score 1):

I've not sure if this is a good idea or not, but you can nil out the token yourself on get requests from inside your application controller.

```
before_filter :reset_csrf


private
def reset_csrf
  session[:_csrf_token] = nil if request.get?
end
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly, except you can't use it if your page sends multiple AJAX GET requests (e.g. user status updates), so I'd go with "...if request.get? and not request.xhr?". Alas, I can't, because still that approach breaks multi-tab (multi-window) navigation if you have forms on both tabs and intend to use them. Besides XHR can be easily spoofed, which would effectively leave a security hole for the slightly more intelligent attacker. I'm starting to think CSRF protection just doesn't work.

Comment: True, and I know what you mean in your final point. Sorry I don't have more advice to offer on CSRF

Comment: I also get to this point, keeping multiple tabs working is important. My security knowledge is small to report something about it. I use a very weak JS captcha, only to stop spam bots: http://fabianosoriani.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/very-simple-invisible-javascript-rails-captcha/